# TChart lite component features

Tags: delphi, teechart, c++builder-xe4

Does TChart lite component included in RAD Studio XE4 environment support GDI+ rendering or not ? Feature matrix doesnt tak about it.

http://www.steema.com/featurematrix/vcl

Searching in installation directory I found file VCLTee.TeeGDIPlus.hpp containing declaration of class TGDIPlusCanvas.

If yes then how to enable it ?

Comment: `Chart1.Canvas := TGDIPlusCanvas.Create;`

Comment: P.S. to modify GDI+ canvas properties, use e.g. `TGDIPlusCanvas(Chart1.Canvas).AntiAlias := ...`. Or declare a variable of type `TGDIPlusCanvas` which you assign to the chart's `Canvas`. Steema's default setup looks, err, not quite well (or maybe I'm just spoiled by the AGG library, don't know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To activate GDIPlus in C++Builder applications, add the header to the .h:

```
#include <VclTee.TeeGDIPlus.hpp>
```

And then create the Canvas directly:

```
Chart1->Canvas = new TGDIPlusCanvas();
```

or through a variable:

```
TGDIPlusCanvas *myGDIPlus = new TGDIPlusCanvas();
Chart1->Canvas = myGDIPlus;
```